# how to update image when i have my function

Tags: laravel

I'm having problem with this code in update photo:
I already have function on it but it doesnt work

```
if (isset($request['image'])) {
    $image = request()->file('image')->move("pictures/{$users[0]['username']}", 'public');
}
if (isset($request['licenseimage_front'])) {
    $request['licenseimage_front'] = request()->file('licenseimage_front')->store("licensepicture/front/{$users[0]['username']}", 'public');
}
if (isset($request['licenseimage_back'])) {
    $request['licenseimage_back'] = request()->file('licenseimage_back')->store("licensepicture/back/{$users[0]['username']}", 'public');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please cick on edit link and format the question to make it readable.

Comment: "I already have function on it but it doesnt work" - how it might works, can you provide this info? Any errors?

Comment: There's no error every time i upload the profile pic it will not display, also in the database

Comment: Use `hasFile()` instead of `isset()` i.e. `request()->hasFile('image')`.

Comment: error "Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\hasFile()"